# Target all x elements with sibling y

Tags: jquery

how can I target all elements  that have a sibling  (and only those) in jQuery?

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">target</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">no target</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">no target</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(":not(:only-child)")
```

See [jquery selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors). The definition of [`:only-child`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/onlyChild) is:

> Matches all elements that are the only
>   child of their parent.